# Edit python configuration file to contain Grobid path

Tags: python, grobid

I have installed Robot-reviewer from github following all the passages. I'm at one of the last passages where it asks

"Edit the robotreviewer/config.py file to contain the path to the directory where you have installed Grobid. (RobotReviewer will start it automatically in a subprocess). Note that this should be the path to the entire (parent) Grobid directory, not the bin subfolder."

Unfortunately I didn't find any tutorial to do this and I'm not practical with python. How can i accomplish this?

The github link for this repo is https://github.com/ijmarshall/robotreviewer3

Comment: It might be a typo. The `config.json` looks much more likely to be the one where to edit the path.

Comment: thanks it was that, you can add it as response so I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a typo in the `README.md`.

The `config.py` is the module that loads the configuration and the actual configuration is in the `config.json` file.

Thus, `config.json` is actually where you're expected to make changes.

(However, other Python projects sometimes indeed use Python files for configuration, so you cannot generalize that you should never touch them.)